# Running multiple commands in terminal

Tags: terminal

I'm told to run this command on terminal:

```
sudo env PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin /usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 unstartup launchd -u dora --hp /Users/dora
```

It seems like it's multiple commands in one line:

```
sudo env PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 unstartup launchd -u dora --hp /Users/dora
```

But, how does that work? I know A;B, A&&B, A||B, but this looks like A B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It indeed are multiple commands which get run here. If you look up `man env` you'll find

```
SYNOPSIS
    env [-iv] [-P altpath] [-S string] [-u name] [name=value ...] [utility [argument ...]]
```

which explains that `env` does, among other things,

- assign values to variables (the `[name=value ...]` bit which in your case is `PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin /usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2`)
- and then runs another program passed as an argument (the `[utility [argument ...]]` bit, in your case the call to `npm`).

The intention here is to extend the search PATH of the command run through `sudo` in order to have `npm` find all the executables it needs.

This is purely a feature of `env`, other commands like `sudo` or `xargs` have similar capabilities. OTOH `A;B`, `A && B` or `A || B` are shell features.

Comment: That makes sense! I was using sudo all along and didn't notice that it was actually taking an extra command. Thanks @nohillside